# How to set NumberFormat to Number with 0 decimal places

Tags: vba, excel, number-formatting

The below VBA in MS Access is run to format my Excel sheet. However, it is formatting to Number with 2 decimal places. How do I specify that I want 0 decimal places?

```
            wb.Sheets(1).Range("K:AD").Formula = wb.Sheets(1).Range("K:AD").Value
            wb.Sheets(1).Range("K:AD").NumberFormat = "Number"
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
 wb.Sheets(1).Range("K:AD").NumberFormat = "0"
```